# Ping outside LAN not working with Mikrotik router

Tags: ping, mikrotik-routeros

I try to ping outside internet from Mikrotik terminal but I can't. I have Mikrotik routerboard 750GL. I tried to ping gmail.com, It's IP is: 74.125.236.53

> ping 74.125.236.53

I got output:

> timout

But If I ping my local system from Mikrotik terminal I am able to do, my local system IP is:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

> ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

I got output:

> connected

Why can not I able to ping outside my LAN connection?

Comment: what happens when you `ping 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: I got this when try `ping 8.8.8.8` [myuser@MikroTik] > ping 8.8.8.8
Output:   
`8.8.8.8                                                 timeout     
8.8.8.8                                                 timeout`

Comment: Sounds like you either do not have an internet connection or your router is blocking the ping service outbound.

Comment: but I am able to `ping 8.8.8.8` from my local system, I mean I do ping through router but not from within router

Comment: Was there a firewall rule in the NAT table to masquerade everything going out into your network?

Comment: As You can ping 8.8.8.8 from lan, but not from router, look at firewall filter/mangle/nat, routing etc

Answer (score 1):

Go to IP -> Firewall -> NAT, click the blue `+` to add a rule, Chain is `srcnat`, Out interface is `ether1` - or whatever `ether` you get your internet from. Then go to the Action tab and select `Masquerade`.